# OPENROWSET on sp_executesql with two dynamic parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, openrowset

Can someone give me a working example of using `OPENROWSET` on SQL Server with dynamic SQL (`sp_executesql`) executing a stored procedure with two parameters as variables, preferably date and integer? I want to use that output and `INSERT INTO` a temp table

```sql
INSERT INTO #t
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
(
    SQL Server
    SP with two parameters date and integer)
   
SELECT * FROM #t
```

Comment: Why not use a Linked Server? Then just a normal `INSERT ... EXEC LinkedServer.Db.Schema.Proc ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for dynamic SQL. You can find extensive coverage [here](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#BULKINSERT) and [here](https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY).

```sql
DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(MAX),  
        @params nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @params = N'@YourDate    date, 
                   @YourInt     int'

SELECT @sql = 
    'INSERT INTO #t
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(
            ''Provided Name, e.g. SQLNCLI'',
            ''Provided String e.g. Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
            ''EXEC YourProcedure @YourDate, @YourInt'')'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @YourDate = '20220101', @YourInt = 12345

SELECT * FROM #t
```

[This dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m7n8yDgV) shows that the `PRINT`'s output looks correct, but I must admit that I don't have the right setup on my end to actually test the `EXEC`.

Comment: You cannot parametrise an OPENROWSET query like that. Whatever `@name` sequences the query argument of OPENROWSET may contain cannot be processed as arguments by `sp_executesql`, because they are inside a string literal as far as `sp_executesql` is concerned.  You will have to concatenate the actual values into the query as literals: `SET @sql = '…OPENROWSET(…, ''EXEC YourProcedure ' + …  /* expression for the first argument, appropriately quoted if necessary */ + ', ' + …  /* second argument, appropriately quoted if necessary */ + ''')'; PRINT @sql; INSERT INTO #t EXEC sp_executesql @sql; …`.

Comment: @AndriyM Oh. You're right. It's just the `EXEC` line that needs to change, right?

Comment: The EXEC line inside the OPENROWSET needs to be built dynamically, yes.  The `EXEC sp_executesql` line needs to lose the arguments after the `@sql` as well.

Comment: @AndriyM [Like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/bnug4_RH)? This is awful.

Comment: The one given in the above link to the https://dbfiddle.uk/bnug4_RH site runs fine if just print is used. If EXEC @SQL is run, it throws an error saying unclosed quotation mark after the charcter string 'Exec .....'

Comment: @mkSQL Oh. It probably just needs an extra `''` before the bracket is closed. I think you want the line to be `+ ''')'` .

Comment: @J.Mini: [Slightly worse](https://dbfiddle.uk/VvgEfpuQ), because the date value needs to be (double-)quoted inside the OPENROWSET query.